# With the Java Sync MongoDB Driver, how do you acertain the impact of an aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

I have code in Java that performs an aggregation pipeline roughly:

```java
List<Bson> aggUpdate = Arrays.asList(
   match(...),
   project(...),
   lookup(...),
   ...
   merge(...)
);
AggregateIterable<?> result = mongoClient.getDatabase(...).getCollection(...).aggregate(aggUpdate);
result.toCollection(); // this kicks off the execution of the merge
```

Take note: the `merge` stage is last in my pipeline--I'm using this query to update a document in my collection (if conditions are correct).

What I've found is that `result` is not helpful at all for me to be able to determine what happened (in my case it should update 0 or 1 document).  Do I need to run a separate query to figure out what happened?

I've tried to use the `iterator()` of the `AggregateIterable` result, but it does something even more befuddling: it returns *every* document in the collection (regardless of whether it matched in the first stage or not!).  Seems like a very bad / useless cursor.

Comment: `...aggregate(aggUpdate)` executes the pipeline, and returns the result as a cursor. Having `$merge` (or `$out`) as the last operation in an aggregation pipeline returns an empty cursor. This is because  the stages `$merge` and `$out` write to a collection. Read the documentation for details.

Comment: @prasad_ you're wrong (at least for Java sync driver 4.5.1--I am running the test)  I'm more than familiar with the documentation.  In case you missed it, that documentation mentions that the cursor is empty when `$out` is the last stage.  Not `$merge`.  From a user perspective having the "results" of an aggregation pipeline ending with a merge be every document in the collection is not very useful.

Comment: I was referring to the native query.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my only answer for now is: persist a "verification value" with the aggregation query (in my case a simple timestamp), and then execute a separate query after aggregation that ensures the "verification value" is set as expected.